# Aligning Data in SQL

Tags: sybase

I am using Sybase SQL.

I have two tables.

Table A:

```
Column1_A:
100
501
504
810
810
950
955
955
```

Table B:

```
Column1_B:
100
250
503
810
807
949
950
955
955
```

I want to achieve the following:

```
Column1_A    Column1_B
100          NULL   
501          250
504          503
810          503
810          503
950          949
955          950
955          950
```

So, basically I want to align the Column1_B from Table B to Column1_A from Table A so that maximum of Column1_B is less than Column1_A for each row. It should give NULL if there is no such element in Table B

The values in the Column1_A or Column1_B are for illustration only. The real values are like 1000, 1500, 2504, and they not necessarily the values in Column1_B are Column1_A - 1.

### Edit:

I modified the data so that logic can be generalized. I am using Sybase SQL.

Comment: Isn't there an identity column, or PK/FK value in the tables to join on?  Also, what Sybase product are you using: Sybase ASE or SQLAnywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but it's not clear for me what you want to obtain. But final result that you presented could be obtained by:

```
SELECT Column1_A, Column1_B FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON Column1_A = Column1_B -1
```

Edit. 
You might try a correlated subquery then:

SELECT Column1_A a, (SELECT MAX(Column1_B) FROM B where Column1_B < a) FROM A

Comment: I modified the data so can you please give me a new code example? Thanks